# Комплексный запрос Spring Data

Tags: sql, база-данных, spring, crud

**Нужно найти весь список продуктов по code категории.**
Есть следующие Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
```

public class Product {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
@Column(unique = true)
private String code;
private String name;
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinTable(name = "products_categories",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "product_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "category_id")})
@JsonIgnoreProperties("products")
private Set<Category> categories;
```

}

И

```
@Entity
```

@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
@Column(unique = true)
private String code;
private String name;
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE},mappedBy = "categories")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "categories")
private Set<Product> products;
```

}

В итоге есть три таблицы в БД: Продукты, категории и таблица связывающая их ID.
[image: Products]

[image: Categories]

[image: Общая]

**Нужно найти весь список продуктов по code категории.**

Пробовала через JPQL , но на `"from Products p where p.categories"` дальше не ушло.
На нативном SQL тоже ничего не выходит 
`Select product.id, product.name, product. code from products, categories, products_categories where categories.code = ?1`

Хочется красиво найти все продукты за 1 или 2 запроса, не залазя в CategoryRepository, а обращаясь только к ProductRepository , которые `extends CrudRepository`
или хотяб понять как за один запрос найти коллекцию Id всех искомых продуктов но не могу найти никаких сложных примеров чтоб понять как делать мой =(

Answer (score 0):

Перечитав Бена форта нашла решение :

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN (SELECT product_id FROM products_categories WHERE category_id = (SELECT id FROM categories WHERE code = ?1))
```